# Web-scraping Program will Randomly Not Work - Return Empty List

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web-scraping and am running into a recurrent problem. I have a script that grabs information on upcoming ticket prices from stubhub and is programmed to run daily to collect data on teams, dates, and cheapest price. My script ran fine for a couple of days before attempts to extract prices using BeautifulSoup would come up empty. A day later, the program ran again as expected without changes. Now it's not working again, and hasn't run properly in more than a week. I'm really scratching my head over this, as I haven't made any changes to the code, and attempts at work arounds have come up empty handed.

Here's the snippet of code:

```
#import modules 
import requests,bs4,re
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil import parser

# StubHub
user_agent= UserAgent()
header = {'User-Agent':str(user_agent.chrome)}
res = requests.get('https://www.stubhub.com/washington-capitals-tickets/performer/762/',headers=header)
res.raise_for_status()

#parse
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

# list of prices for events 
links_tix = soup.find_all("div",class_="EventItem__Price")
tix_re = '\d+'
prices = [] 
for i in links_tix: # find list of cheapest prices  
    prices.append(re.findall(tix_re,str(i)))
```

Any suggestions on what might cause the soup.findall() method to come up empty would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it pick up on you being a bot and block? It worked the first time I ran with selenium then after returned nothing.

Comment: Web scraping is hard. You are probably getting blocked by the web server. There are ways to circumvent blocking which are off topic for Stack Overflow. I suggest you to read some articles about web scraping, proxies, and user agents.

Comment: It looks like there are measures being used on the site to counteract automated access like your script. It's possible to work around these, but if you're after just StubHub data they have an API available. [This article](http://ozzieliu.com/2016/06/21/scraping-ticket-data-with-stubhub-api/) implements it in python and should be a good starting point.